# Are you allowed to repost closed questions from stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

This was a great question that ultimately got closed on stackoverflow:

[How do you give estimates for Magento upgrade? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736211/how-do-you-give-estimates-for-magento-upgrade)

In general are you allowed to simply repost relevant questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this particular question - Yes!

The reason it was closed at SO is it was not programming related. However this site allows non-programming Magento related questions.

So generally speaking if question violated SO rules but not magento.stackexchange it can be safely posted.

Comment: Hi :) What's next? Should I post this question or somebody else have to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @ceckoslab: Do it!

Comment: I was going to post it but wanted to give you the honors :)  Was a great question.